# Templating engine for Codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, rest, template-engine

I am new to **Codeigniter** and want to use it as **RESTful** api front. I have already an API created with Phalcon and MongoDB.
Is there any way to use any kind of **Templating engine** in Codeigniter views, that can parse the JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

When I was studying codeignitor while developing a webapp I used [smarty](http://www.smarty.net) 
It was pretty good open source template engine